# JS Switchery doesn't work

Tags: javascript

I use switchery.js for my project https://github.com/abpetkov/switchery

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/switchery.css">
  <script src="js/switchery.js"></script>
  <script>
      var Switchery = require('switchery');

var elems = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.switchery'));

elems.forEach(function(html) {
    var switchery = new Switchery(html);
});
    </script>
  <body>
    <div id="wrapper">
      ... 
          <div id="screen-2"><input type="checkbox" class="switchery"></div>
      ...
      
      </div>
    </body>
```

But the problem is, that it looks like the standart checkbox. 
Help pls!

Comment: Probably: [Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as getElementById not find the element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element)

Comment: `html` isn't a good var name there.